# To refresh a javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, refresh, setinterval

Good, I have a javascript that got thanks to this site, which comes from an XML document whose link is: http://inlivefm.6te.net/NowOnAir.xml, javascript must remove functionality as the artist name and song xml document.
What I intend to do is to add the javascript code to refresh the artist name and song automatically.

I tried but could not get this result, below I leave the javascript with the "attempt" to refresh.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
          /*  Busca el archivo NowOnAir.xml */
          $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/NowOnAir.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                /*Buscar el tag <Event> e ir repitiendo el proceso hasta el final (bucle) */
                $(xml).find('Event').each(function(){
                    /*Tomar los valores de startTime*/
                    var startTime = $(this).attr('startTime');

                    /*Buscar el tag <Song> y repetir bucle*/
                    $(this).find('Song').each(function(){
                        /*Tomar los valores de title*/
                        var title = $(this).attr('title');
                        var artist;

                        /*Buscar el tag <Artist> y repetir bucle*/
                        $(this).find('Artist').each(function(){
                            /*Tomar los valores de name*/
                            artist = $(this).attr('name');
                        });

                        /*Buscar el tag Expire y repetir bucle*/
                        $(this).find('Expire').each(function(){
                            var time = $(this).attr('Time');
                            $('.cancion').append("<p>"+artist+" - "+title+"</p>");
                            setInterval(function(){$('.cancion');}, 5000);
                        });
                    });
                });
            }
          });
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="cancion"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I must be to make a mistake, so I came to ask your help.

Since already thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The main thing that could cause errors is that `closing braces & brackets` are missing in a few places.
2. Use `setInterval` function to automatically refresh your content.

   ```
   <script>

   $(document).ready(function(){
   get_info();
   setInterval(function(){ get_info(); }, 20000);

   function get_info(){

           $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "NowOnAir.xml",
               dataType: "xml",
               success: function(xml) {                     
                     $(xml).find('Event').each(function(){                                  
                     $(this).find('Song').each(function(){                
                     var title = $(this).attr('title');
                     var artist;                

                     $(this).find('Artist').each(function(){                    
                       artist = $(this).attr('name');
                     });                

                     $(this).find('Expire').each(function(){                    
                     $('.cancion').append("<p>"+artist+" - "+title+"</p>");
                   });
                 });
               });
             }
          });
   }
   });

   </script>
   ```

if You need to replace the content of your `<div>` on every `$.ajax` call then
use `.html()` method.

```
$('#content-wr').html('<div class="new-lines"><div><a>' + val.id + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + val.joke + '</a></div></div>');
```

and check this example:

```js
setInterval(function(){    
  $.ajax ({
    url: 'http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random',
    method: 'GET',
    beforeSend: function(){
      $('#content-wr').children().fadeOut(1500);
    },
    success: function(data){
      var val = data.value
      $('#content-wr').append('<div class="new-lines"><div><a>' + val.id + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + val.joke + '</a></div></div>');
    }
    });    
},5000);
```

```css
.new-lines > div{
  width: 500px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content-wr"></div>
```

Your `ajax` will be called and content updated/refreshed every 5 seconds.

Or put your `ajax` call inside `get_info()` function.

Comment: I tried again as you said and I can not get what I want, I could change the javascript as you are saying, I would be very grateful. Thanks!

Comment: @AndréSantos please check `code snippet` provided with my answer.

Comment: I put the code that you provided and I was aware of every step your good example but I still can not do refresh, there is no other way to make simpler refresh?

Comment: I edited the post, based on that code what I lack to achieve refresh, because I using the setInterval (function () {                                   all content disappears

Comment: @AndréSantos, another way is to put `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="20">` inside `<head>`. This method will reload entire page, not only content inside some element.

Comment: what I wanted was only the content that is inside the javascript, I'm going back to look at the examples and try to put the automatic refrsh. Thank you

Comment: @AndréSantos, as `$('.cancion')` is not a function `setInterval` in your code is useless. I'll update my answer with working example of Your code.

Comment: I thought it was there that I atualizava the music and the song that's why I'm calling $ ('. cancion'), but apparently I'm wrong

Comment: It's been the refresh of the song, (<div class = "cancion"> <p> MAROON 5 - MAPS </ p> </ div>) but what happened was past few minutes had the name repeated several times song (<div class = "cancion"> <p> MAROON 5 - MAPS </ p> <p> MAROON 5 - MAPS </ p> <p> MAROON 5 - MAPS </ p> <p> MAROON 5 - MAPS </ p > <p> MAROON 5 - MAPS </ p> <p> MAROON 5 - MAPS </ p> </ div>), what I wanted was just to refresh (<div class = "cancion"> <p> MAROON 5 - MAPS </ p> </ div>) without appearing so often the name  I've tried changing the getinfo but to no avail

Comment: @AndréSantos, then use `.html()` instead of `.append()` as I suggested before.

Comment: Everything working right, thank you for dedication in solving this problem, hug!